# Number value getting rounded in Excel

Tags: excel

I want to put numbers in Excel File.
When I am putting 2020092810280315532 in excel, excel is automatically converting it to 2020092810280310000.

How can I avoid this?

Comment: Put a `'` in front - you need to store the number as text.

Comment: @BigBen: Assuming the intent is to *use* this number in a calculation, that doesn't really solve the problem.

Comment: Agreed but Excel is limited as you well know.